# What will be Redirect URI type (web/Native) for Power Bi dataset refresh from Azure Data factory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, powerbi

I've a requirement of refreshing the Power BI dataset from Azure data factory. I want to do it by calling the Power BI Rest API service. For authentication process I need a access token which I can get using a Client ID and secret. So, while registering the app I was wondering what type of redirect URI should I select? And how does it link with my task because I'm neither creating any web app or native app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding MS docs about creating Daemon application for authorization:
"During application registration, the reply URI isn't needed. You need to share secrets or certificates or signed assertions with Azure AD. You also need to request application permissions and grant admin consent to use those app permissions."

Please, read a whole documentation over here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-daemon-overview

Comment: Ok..Thank you. So, does It really matter whether I'm selecting the type 'web' or 'native' at reply URI optional section?  or will it make any difference?

Comment: @Sanjibsrkr By following the documentation, you should not set them in the Daemon example.